# How to wrap the elements within the parent in jQuery

Tags: jquery

By using jQuery, how do I wrap the `<a>` tags in a `<p>` tag within the parent div.

I don't have any control on HTML to add unique classes. Please help, Thanks..

**My Current HTML:**

```
<div class="content">
    <a href="#" class="anchor">some anchor link</a>
    <a href="#" class="anchor">some anchor link</a>
    <p>some paragraph content</p>
</div>
<div class="content">
    <a href="#" class="anchor">some anchor link</a>
    <a href="#" class="anchor">some anchor link</a>
    <p>some paragraph content</p>
</div>
```

**My current jQuery:**

```
$( ".anchor" ).wrapAll( "<p class='new'></p>" );
```

**My Current Output:**

```
<div class="content">
  <p class="new">
    <a href="#" class="anchor">some anchor link</a>
    <a href="#" class="anchor">some anchor link</a>
    <a href="#" class="anchor">some anchor link</a>
    <a href="#" class="anchor">some anchor link</a>
  </p>
  <p>some paragraph content</p>
</div>
<div class="content">
  <p>some paragraph content</p>
</div>
```

**But I want output like this:**

```
<div class="content">
  <p class="new">
    <a href="#" class="anchor">some anchor link</a>
    <a href="#" class="anchor">some anchor link</a>
  </p>
  <p>some paragraph content</p>
</div>
<div class="content">
  <p class="new">
    <a href="#" class="anchor">some anchor link</a>
    <a href="#" class="anchor">some anchor link</a>
  </p>
  <p>some paragraph content</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need .each from the content level

```js
$(".content").each(function() {
  $(this).find(".anchor").wrapAll("<p class='new'></p>");
})
```

```css
.new  { background-color: grey }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="content">
  <a href="#" class="anchor">some anchor link</a>
  <a href="#" class="anchor">some anchor link</a>
  <p>some paragraph content</p>
</div>
<div class="content">
  <a href="#" class="anchor">some anchor link</a>
  <a href="#" class="anchor">some anchor link</a>
  <p>some paragraph content</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can loop over a ".content" class and find all anchor and wrap it. something like below.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".content").each(function() {
  let current=$(this);
  current.find(".anchor").wrapAll("<p class='new'></p>");
});
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="content">
    <a href="#" class="anchor">some anchor link</a>
    <a href="#" class="anchor">some anchor link</a>
    <p>some paragraph content</p>
</div>
<div class="content">
    <a href="#" class="anchor">some anchor link</a>
    <a href="#" class="anchor">some anchor link</a>
    <p>some paragraph content</p>
</div>
```